# Twitter Bootstrap responsive thumbnails: how to cure indentation on second row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5dXc/show/

Any idea how I can cure the indentation after the 4th thumbnail?

Here is the source: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5dXc/

Looking at the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails) under the 'more examples' heading, I can see their 2 row example but I can't make it work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't really explain it well in the demo but if you use the `<div class="row-fluid">`around it you have to make another row for the next line of thumbnails. If you want to just make a bunch of thumbnails that are not `fluid` you can just use a regular `<div>` or `<p>`. This should be raised as an issue against Bootstrap so it can be fixed.

Answer (score 7):

I've found the same issue and didn't find an elegant solution. I'm using this little hack:

```
.thumbnails .span4:nth-child(3n+1),
.thumbnails .span4:first-child + li + li + li,
.thumbnails .span4:first-child + li + li + li + li + li + li {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Note that the long series of `li` are the IE way, and you must add one of them for each row.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for thumbnails](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails) doesn't allude to responsive design but a predefined `row` with `.span*` children:

`...the thumbnails component uses existing grid system classes - like .span2 or .span3 - for control of thumbnail dimensions.`

To have chldren of `.span2`,`.span3`,`.span4` or `.span6` the following [patch](https://gist.github.com/appastair/5723225#file-thumbnails-less-diff) works with modern browsers and Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2:

```
.row-fluid .thumbnails .span2:nth-child(6n+1), 
    .row-fluid .thumbnails .span3:nth-child(4n+1), 
    .row-fluid .thumbnails .span4:nth-child(3n+1), 
    .row-fluid .thumbnails .span6:nth-child(2n+1) {
        margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported issue on the official bootstrap github, so I suggest anyone looking for more solutions to check that out - [twitter bootstrap on github.com](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3494).

As of this moment the issue hasn't been resolved, but various users have submitted 10+ different solutions in the comment thread there.